# Excel Not Rendering Correct Page Layout in Protected View

Tags: microsoft-excel

One of the employees at my company is trying to publish some Excel files to our website (employee login only). The spreadsheet is rather large (12 columns wide), but there are no plans to convert it to dead-tree format; it's intended to stay digital. As such, the page layout is set to custom size landscape. When the spreadsheet is downloaded from our website, Excel opens it in protected view, which is expected since it's coming from a website. However, the protected view mode seems to be ignoring any page formatting, rendering it on 8.5x11 protrait pages, only allowing ~4 columns per page, and splitting it onto several horizontal pages.

I know that protected view is supposed to stop scripts etc from infecting computers, but is there any way to allow page formatting to be correctly displayed in protected view? I won't have access to every computer the file will be opened on, so default MS Office settings on the client-end would be preferred.

Comment: Maybe print to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue at my company.  I needed Excel to open files without protected view so the macros would run to enable the interface, and protected view confused the users so they could not get the application to run.

Excel will not open files in protected view if they are from a trusted location.  The best way to do this in an organization is through your domain's Group Policy.  If I remember correctly, I needed to make two changes in group policy: 1) set your website as a trusted site in GP > Computer Configuration > Administrative Tools > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Security > Site to Zone assignment; and 2) you should set the network location the Excel files are being shared from as a trusted location for Microsoft Office using [Office Group Policy Administrative Templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179176(v=office.14).aspx#Administrative_templates), which must be installed and configured in your domain.

You can also use Office GP Admin Templates to [disable protected view entirely](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/3687-turn-off-office-2010-protected-view-with-group-policy), but I would not advise it.

It's a lot of work to circumvent these measures that Microsoft has put in place to protect us from malicious code, but alas, such is the age we live in.

Comment: If it were me, I would [publish it as a Google doc spreadsheet](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37579) and put the link on your website.